# JBOSS ESB 5.3 JSON proxy

Tags: java, json, jboss, esb

Actually I have REST endpoints that accept GET and POST requests on a remote Windows Server using IIS application with Web API, but these endpoints must be reachable through JBOSS ESB 5.3 community too.
I don't want to transform incoming JSON requests, just send the url segments and  request body when POST to the REST endpoints, and do the same for JSON response body too when sending back to the client.

It would be a kind of reverse proxy functionality I think.
Well I am new to JAVA, JBOSS, ESB.

thanks,
Balazs